# Change the availability date to 2 weeks later while the application had been approved and on the market now - iTunnes Connect

Tags: ios, date, app-store-connect

Can I change the availability date for application to 2 weeks late while the 1st availability date setting is today?

Any effect for the application?

I just want the application available 2 weeks later on the app store.

Thanks

Comment: When application is approved and on the iTunes you can't change the availability date anymore. Obviously because it is available now.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is still waiting for review you can adjust the availability date to any date you want. If your app is already approved and its status is already ready for sale then you can remove the app from sale, and release it after 2 weeks manually.